# React-Bootstrap Modal form entry

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I currently have a React Bootstrap Modal that when opened, shows a number of Inputs. I want the user to be able to enter values in the Inputs, and then with a 'Save' button, simply to create a JSON object and console log the newly created JSON object.

```
closeModal(){
    this.setState({
      showModal: false,
    });
}

openModal(){
    this.setState({
      showModal: true,
    });
}

saveSandbox(event){
    console.log("Hello World");
    name: this.refs.bundleName.findDOMNode().value;
    console.log(name);
}
<Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.closeModal.bind(this)}>
    <form>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Create New</Modal.Title>
            <Input type="text" ref="bundleName" placeholder="Name" />
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body >
            <h4>Type: </h4>

                <Input type="select" placeholder="select">
                    {bundleTypes.map(({type}, index) =>
                        <option value="select">{type}</option>
                    )}
                </Input>

                    <h4>Description: </h4>
                    <Input type="text" placeholder="Enter text"}/>
                    <hr />

        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.saveSandbox.bind(this)} bsStyle="success">Save</Button>
            <Button onClick={this.closeModal.bind(this)} >Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
    </form>
</Modal>
```

This is my code currently, however when ran in Chrome, it reports that `Uncaught TypeError: this.refs.bundleName.findDOMNode is not a function`

When looking at examples or other questions/answers the suggestions are now deprecated.

Comment: Could you try this one `React.findDOMNode(this.refs.bundleName)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **React v0.14** it is straight forward.
Following code - `this.refs.bundleName` is the actual DOM node.
You don't have to call `this.refs.bundleName.getDOMNode()` to get the underlying DOM node.

Comment: Thanks that worked correctly, I then used `.getValue()` and it worked as expected